# Opening Realm files of format version 5 is not supported by this version of Realm

Tags: swift, migration, realm

I can't find a way to read my Realm file. I assumed Realm is backwards compatible. The Realm objects/attributes/classes have remained exactly the same. I tried changing the schema and also tried custom migration, which is impossible because I get "Opening Realm files of format version 5 is not supported by this version of Realm" as soon as I tried to read from Realm. I have tried many tricks i've read in other posts such as forcing readOnly to false:

```
    let version = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.schemaVersion
    print("schema version \(version)")
    var configuration = Realm.Configuration(readOnly: false, schemaVersion: 1)
    try! Realm(configuration: configuration)   //FAILS Opening Realm files of format version 5 is not supported by this version of Realm
    configuration = Realm.Configuration(readOnly: true)
    let realm = try! Realm(configuration: configuration)
```

I can't update the app on the App Store because people with a previous version will have their app crash, and I don't want to delete their Realm file and get bad reviews because they lost all their data. Is there any option without downgrading to an earlier version of realm?

I'm using XCode 12.4 and swift 5. The schema of the Realm file is unchanged. The issue was supposed to be solved in Realm v5.4.1 on 9/20/2021. I have the latest version of Realm installed but the issue is not resolved.   https://swift.libhunt.com/realm-cocoa-changelog?page=4
I've have also tried resetting the integration state:

```
pod cache clean Realm
pod cache clean RealmSwift
pod deintegrate || rm -rf Pods
pod install --verbose
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

My version info:

```
tee /dev/tty | pbcopy
ProductName:    macOS
ProductVersion: 11.1
BuildVersion:   20C69
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
Xcode 12.4
Build version 12D4e
/Users/Paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin/pod 
1.10.1
Realm (10.5.1)
RealmSwift (10.5.1)
/bin/bash
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin20)
/usr/bin/git
git version 2.24.3 (Apple Git-128)
```

My Pod File:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '12.0'

 target 'Vending Receipt' do
 # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
 use_frameworks!

 # Pods for Vending Receipt
 pod 'Realm'
 pod 'RealmSwift' #, :git => 'https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.git', :branch => 'master'
 pod 'BTNavigationDropdownMenu'
 pod 'SCLAlertView', :git => 'https://github.com/vikmeup/SCLAlertView-Swift.git'

   target 'Vending ReceiptTests' do 
      inherit! :search_paths
 use_frameworks!
     # Pods for testing
 pod 'Realm'
 pod 'RealmSwift' #, :git => 'https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.git', :branch => 'master'
 pod 'BTNavigationDropdownMenu'
 pod 'SCLAlertView', :git => 'https://github.com/vikmeup/SCLAlertView-Swift.git'
   end
 end


 post_install do |installer|
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
          target.build_configurations.each do |config|
              config.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = 'arm64'
              config.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=watchsimulator*]'] = 'arm64'
              config.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=appletvsimulator*]'] = 'arm64'
             config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0'
          end
      end
  end
```

The crash log is below:

Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=io.realm Code=6 "Opening Realm files of format version 5 is not supported by this version of Realm" UserInfo={Error Code=6, NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/04864A2A-4605-49B2-893F-15F76F60DD9B/Documents/default.realm, Underlying=Database has an unsupported version (5) and cannot be upgraded
Exception backtrace:

0   Realm                               0x000000010104e4ac _ZN5realm2DB7do_openERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEEbbNS_9DBOptionsE + 5356
1   Realm                               0x0000000101050694 _ZN5realm2DB4openERNS_11ReplicationENS_9DBOptionsE + 244

2   Realm                               0x000000010105517c _ZN5realm2DB6createERNS_11ReplicationENS_9DBOptionsE + 392

3   Realm                               0x0000000100b5cf40 _ZN5realm5_impl16RealmCoordinator7open_dbEv + 992

4   Realm                               0x0000000100b5c148 _ZN5realm5_impl16RealmCoordinator12do_get_realmENS_5Realm6ConfigERNSt3__110shared_ptrIS2_EENS_4util8OptionalINS_9VersionIDEEERNS8_17CheckedUniqueLockE + 68

5   Realm                               0x0000000100b5bf64 _ZN5realm5_impl16RealmCoordinator9get_realmENS_5Realm6ConfigENS_4util8OptionalINS_9VersionIDEEE + 668

6   Realm                               0x0000000100e4f204 _ZN5realm5Realm16get_shared_realmENS0_6ConfigE + 176

7   Realm                               0x0000000100db93d4 +[RLMRealm realmWithConfiguration:queue:error:] + 1796

8   RealmSwift                          0x0000000102a6f478 $sSo8RLMRealmC13configuration5queueABSo0A13ConfigurationC_So012OS_dispatch_C0CSgtKcfCTO + 156

9   RealmSwift                          0x0000000102ac8734 $s10RealmSwift0A0V13configuration5queueA2C13ConfigurationV_So012OS_dispatch_D0CSgtKcfC + 216

10  Vending Receipt                     0x000000010050d0cc $s15Vending_Receipt0B7StorageC11getReceipts_5sort15sort29ascending10RealmSwift7ResultsVyAA0B0CGSS_S2SSbtF + 1572

11  Vending Receipt                     0x00000001004e4868 $s15Vending_Receipt14SearchReceiptsC11UpdateTableyyF + 1980

12  Vending Receipt                     0x00000001004e11d0 $s15Vending_Receipt14SearchReceiptsC11viewDidLoadyyF + 5768

13  Vending Receipt                     0x00000001004e1250 $s15Vending_Receipt14SearchReceiptsC11viewDidLoadyyFTo + 32

14  UIKitCore                           0x00000001a72f2e50 CC6E5AC7-8248-35F6-8B42-2E25C93DCF0A + 4623952

15  UIKitCore                           0x00000001a72f7408 CC6E5AC7-8248-35F6-8B42-2E25C93DCF0A + 4641800

16  UIKitCore                           0x00000001a72f77e8 CC6E5AC7-8248-35F6-8B42-2E25C93DCF0A + 4642792

17  UIKitCore                           0x00000001a722b738 CC6E5AC7-8248-35F6-8B42-2E25C93DCF0A + 3807032

18  UIKitCore                           0x00000001a723fbb0 CC6E5AC7-8248-35F6-8B42-2E25C93DCF0A + 3890096

19  UIKitCore                           0x00000001a7240fe0 CC6E5AC7-8248-35F6-8B42-2E25C93DCF0A + 3895264

20  UIKitCore                           0x00000001a7223e78 CC6E5AC7-8248-35F6-8B42-2E25C93DCF0A + 3776120

21  UIKitCore                           0x00000001a7ec2398 CC6E5AC7-8248-35F6-8B42-2E25C93DCF0A + 17007512

22  QuartzCore                          0x00000001a83c7df4 461501DD-204F-3516-9F5D-BDD0BA19FDA1 + 1400308

23  QuartzCore                          0x00000001a83ce398 461501DD-204F-3516-9F5D-BDD0BA19FDA1 + 1426328

24  QuartzCore                          0x00000001a83d96e8 461501DD-204F-3516-9F5D-BDD0BA19FDA1 + 1472232

25  QuartzCore                          0x00000001a8324d7c 461501DD-204F-3516-9F5D-BDD0BA19FDA1 + 732540

26  QuartzCore                          0x00000001a834ef40 461501DD-204F-3516-9F5D-BDD0BA19FDA1 + 905024

27  UIKitCore                           0x00000001a79b6d8c CC6E5AC7-8248-35F6-8B42-2E25C93DCF0A + 11718028

28  UIKitCore                           0x00000001a7a5dac4 CC6E5AC7-8248-35F6-8B42-2E25C93DCF0A + 12401348

29  UIKitCore                           0x00000001a7a54afc CC6E5AC7-8248-35F6-8B42-2E25C93DCF0A + 12364540

30  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001a50cdbf0 F3021642-E3C0-33F8-9911-DD303A6056D0 + 633840

31  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001a50cdaf0 F3021642-E3C0-33F8-9911-DD303A6056D0 + 633584

32  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001a50cce38 F3021642-E3C0-33F8-9911-DD303A6056D0 + 630328

33  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001a50c73e0 F3021642-E3C0-33F8-9911-DD303A6056D0 + 607200

34  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001a50c6ba0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572

35  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001bbe2f598 GSEventRunModal + 160

36  UIKitCore                           0x00000001a79b82f4 CC6E5AC7-8248-35F6-8B42-2E25C93DCF0A + 11723508

37  UIKitCore                           0x00000001a79bd874 UIApplicationMain + 164

38  Vending Receipt                     0x00000001004d3444 main + 88

39  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001a4da5568 0B475C78-3C12-3121-B7F8-2B95B83DAF44 + 5480, NSLocalizedDescription=Opening Realm files of format version 5 is not supported by this version of Realm}: file Vending_Receipt/ReceiptModel.swift, line 52
2021-02-01 15:16:21.102889-0600 Vending Receipt[558:58472] Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=io.realm Code=6 "Opening Realm files of format version 5 is not supported by this version of Realm" UserInfo={Error Code=6, NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/04864A2A-4605-49B2-893F-15F76F60DD9B/Documents/default.realm, Underlying=Database has an unsupported version (5) and cannot be upgraded

Comment: Without digging too far in, Realm is NOT directly, backwards compatible but the Realm files can be upgraded. However, we don't know what you've done to this point - what version of the SDK do you have? What version of Realm Studio are you using? What's specified in your podfile. Did you select the realm file, open is with realm studio and tell it up upgrade? Most of what's in your question is not relevant - we need those other details to help.

Comment: I'm using XCode 12.4 and swift 5. The schema of the Realm file is unchanged. The issue was supposed to be solved in Realm v5.4.1 on 9/20/2021. I have the latest version of Realm installed but the issue is not resolved.   https://swift.libhunt.com/realm-cocoa-changelog?page=4           I've tried also tried resetting the integration state:      pod cache clean Realm
      pod cache clean RealmSwift
     pod deintegrate || rm -rf Pods
     pod install --verbose
     rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

Comment: Please update your question with details - and code is very hard to read in comments. Add those to the question. [5.4.1](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/releases/tag/v5.4.1) addressed an encrypted realm issue. That doesn't seem to the case here. Can you please update your question with your PodFile and also what version the SDK you're using? I think you have a mismatch between your SDK and realm file because it has not been upgrade  but I am just guessing at this point.

Comment: I would suggest you update your podfile with a formal RealmSwift release. Is there a reason you want the latest from github?

Comment: Ive updated above with all the info I have.

Answer (score 2):

The core confusion is in the wording `Realm files of format version 5`.

The **file format version** is a different number from the **Realm SDK Version**.

Unfortunately, I don't think this correspondence of versions is clearly documented anywhere.

Searching the [changelog](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) for mention of *format* is the only way I know.

An important version **probably fixed your upgrade woes** [10.7.1](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1071-release-notes-2021-03-05) which *Restores support for upgrading files from file format 5 (Realm Cocoa 1.x)*

From [my sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Nnket1m5gtDQFn_oKznzgv7-P8Kn6E8FapsiwUrvVfE/edit?usp=sharing) which has much more detail:

- [SDK 10.8.0](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1080-release-notes-2021-06-14) *Generates Realms with format v22*
- [SDK 10.0.0](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1000-rc2-release-notes-2020-10-15) *Generates Realms with format v11*
- [SDK 5.4.0](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#540-release-notes-2020-09-094) *Generates Realms with format v11 also (last of the pre-MongoDB standalone?)*
- SDK 2.4 ... 2.10 *format 6*
- SDK 1.x *format 5*

Comment: Note 10.7.1 fixed the compatibilty migration issue about 5 weeks after this question was asked!

Answer (score 1):

Question was answered on Github:

v5.0.0 dropped support for opening Realm files written by versions before v3.0.0.

We support migrating from 6+ and the 5->6 migration just consisted of recreating the string indexes.